# What is Constraint layout's equivalent in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Can I position a widget based on another widget?
like this:

[Tiled Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFRDe.png)
Without

> flutter_staggered_grid_view Library

Comment: Flutter is a constraint layout at its core.

Comment: @Matt I answered there directly

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no `Widget` similar to `ConstraintLayout` but you can achieve what you want using different widgets, like this example:

```
  class Testing2 extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Flexible(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Flexible(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.deepOrange,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Flexible(
                    flex: 2,
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.lightBlue,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Flexible(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Flexible(
                      flex: 3,
                      child: Container(
                        color: Colors.orange,
                      )),
                  Flexible(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Flexible(
                            flex: 2,
                            child: Container(
                              color: Colors.blue,
                            )),
                        Flexible(child: Container(color: Colors.green))
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      );
    }
```

[image: Result]

Also you can take a look this link to know about Layout Widgets: https://flutter.io/widgets/layout/

Comment: Well all I can say after loads of working on layouts... Its terribly primitive in comparison to our Android's Constraint Layout. Seriously, a long way for flutter UI to go before it can be compared to our Android's layouts. Seems like a flash back of java in 1999!

Comment: sure, and now we have Android Jetpack compose and Swift UI :)

Comment: Agreed Constrain Layout has super powers compared to Flutter layout system.

Comment: To @user3833732 (and the upvoters): can you give examples of layouts that are hard or impossible to achieve in Flutter ?

Comment: It is not the same. Flutter layouts are more like web layouts or javafx. On Android and iOS we have Constraint Layout which is way, way, way easier to work with. I'm struggling to make flutter layouts work like i want, with Constraint layout it is a piece of cake. So i'm also thinking, that this is major downside for flutter. Same goes for Dart instead of Kotlin :(

Comment: I did this layout/demo in a couple of hours  https://twitter.com/diegoveloper/status/1245025342496047105   try doing the same in android and ios too :P

Comment: @felislynx.silae if you really understand flutter, and don't want to waste time but still make beautiful layouts then Supernova or AdobeXD now generate all the layout code for you automatically! All you have to do is draw the layout out! ;-)

Comment: I'm doing i layout that need to be stacked and be flexable. Doing that the flutter way will result in a major codebase for a simple view. No thanks will want to use a library to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

https://github.com/hackware1993/Flutter-ConstraintLayout

Build flexible layouts with constraints, Similar to Android ConstraintLayout.

No matter how complex the layout is and how deep the dependencies are, each child element of ConstraintLayout will only be measured once, This results in extremely high layout performance.